# Java / Selenium Документ в документе

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Есть сайт в котором содержится еще один документ в виде

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
....
<head>
....
<body>
....
    #document
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    ....
</body>
```

Вопрос: как с помощью Selenium/Webdriver найти элемент находящийся во "втором" документе?

Comment: Вложить так не получится. Это не валидно, браузер это трансформирует в другую структуру (проигнорирует второй `doctype`). Поэтому в такой формулировке вопроса - никак.

Comment: Суть в том что такой сайт уже есть, и он работает. Мне нужно только найти в нем нужные мне данные. Если с Webdriver не получится то как еще можно?

Comment: Получить исходный HTML код, токенезировать, найти. Или пройти регуляркой, что проще, но работает хуже. На счет токенизации - не уверен, что на невалидном HTML она будет работать.